# Bug with image in HTML email signature

Tags: html, css, html-email

I have a near basic HTML email signature which works perfectly except for one part. I want the image in the signature to also be a link so that when the recipient clicks the image, they can be redirected to my website. However, I've implemented two different ways which both show different issues.

The first way I tried is below. The `<td>` of the `<tr>` has a background image of the image, and also in the `<tr>` below the `<td>`, there is a `div` of the same size of the image enclosed in a parent `<a>`. The `<div>` has a z-index higher than that of the image and should sit "on top" of the image. Sometimes when sending emails it appears properly, but other times, it appears like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/90y5E.jpg whereby the `<div>` sits above the image.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td background="url('link-to-image')" style="display: block !important; margin-left: -2px !important; width: 165px !important; height: 38px !important; background-image: url('http://www.sykes.capital/sykes-capital-logo.jpg'); background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; padding: 0px;">    </td>
         <a href="link-to-website">
             <div style="position: absolute; z-index: 999; display: block !important; margin-left: -2px !important; width: 165px !important; height: 45px !important; padding: 0px;"></div>
         </a>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

The second way I tried was the below.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <a href="link-to-website">
            <img src="link-to-image" width="165" height="38" />
        </a>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

However doing it this way, it appears like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNwlw.jpg
The raw image that the HTML email signature is fetching is larger than the 165x38 size appearing in the signature, but when I reduce the image size online, this reduces the quality.

I've also tried reducing the DPI to 72, but this didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Your second approach is correct. Use the width and height attributes to control image size, original size does not matter in that case as you can see below, however make sure you keep the correct aspect ratio.

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com">
      <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a" width="101" height="24" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com">
      <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a" width="90" height="100" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com">
      <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a" width="150" height="20" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com">
      <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a" width="90" height="50" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Cray. However, when I did this, in my Mac Mail email client, it appears like https://imgur.com/a/fZQcwO2 instead. I even added the styles `width: 165px !important;` and `height: 38px !important;`, but this did not suffice.

Comment: There must be some additional CSS that messes it up then, can you make a fiddle where I can see the problem. Or try removing the `table` and use `div` instead if you need a surrounding container. Also what happened when you modified the values? Image did not change at all?

Comment: The issue doesn't happen when viewing in a fiddle or web browser, solely in the email client. When I modify the values too, the image doesn't change. It just uses the dimensions that the raw image is set in.

Comment: In that case the easiest solution is to use a image editor like Gimp or Photoshop and simply resize it. This will not cause massive quality loss unlike some of the online tools.

Comment: Another solution using HTML/CSS would be limiting the size of the container element (`div` in my example), if image still remains larger than container you can also set the image to be background of the container. If neither of those work then resizing raw image is the only solution I can come up with.

Comment: I'll try your solutions, and if I get it to work, I'll accept your answer. Thanks for the advice Cray.

Comment: `div`'s are not best approach when it comes to emails, especially Outlooks. They only read it as block elements and it can be made into an inline element.

Answer (score 0):

Coding email is going back to basics. Coding with divs is tricky as you will need fall backs for email clients like Outlook. Background images are the same, Outlooks cause a lot of problems.

You best bet will be to use the second approach but dont miss out the `td`'s (its missing from your example above).

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="link-to-website">
                <img src="link-to-image" width="165" height="38" style="border:0px;display:block;" />
            </a>
        </td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

I added two things to your link:

- **Border 0**: You can place this on the image tag as an attribute or in the style tag, it will do the same thing.
- **Display Block**: Without this the images have a space under it (remove it to see what i mean)

Give the above a try. Also if you are using retina images, keep an eye that the width and height are on the image tag. Outlook's dont read image style that well when it comes to width and height.